# Qcubed Left Join

Tags: sql, join, qcubed

How Can I make a left join in qcode/qcubed and select fields from both tables. ( no FK exists but there are fields that are logical to join ).

Comment: Could you provide an example of the query you are attempting to use?

Answer (score 2):

You can define foreign key relationships without explicit foreign keys in the database - see http://examples.qcu.be/assets/_core/php/examples/code_generator/script_path.php.

If the above is not possible, I'd write a custom SQL query in that case.